# Is it possible to only store a part of my query results in a variable for stored functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm extremely new to PL/SQL in general and am trying out stored functions and procedures.

I have the below select statement:

```
SELECT query1.*
  FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
            FROM orders
        GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query1,
       (SELECT MAX (query2.ordercount) AS orderhighest
          FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
                    FROM orders
                GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query2) query3
 WHERE query1.ordercount = query3.orderhighest;
```

The goal of this select statement is to count the total number of orders for each customer and find the customer with the highest orders. And the query will return CustKey & the total number of orders that's calculated using the OrderKey.

```
         O_CUSTKEY ORDERCOUNT
    ---------- ----------
          9787     41
```

Now I have to find a way to use the Custkey part of the result, insert it into a variable so that I'll be able to use it to query another table for the rest of the customer information.

But I'm not too sure on how to go about doing so. I've heard of using SELECT INTO but I only require the CustKey portion of the query result (i.e. 9787) and not the OrderCount (41).

Edit: I tried changing it into a stored function (with no parameters) based on @Littlefoot's suggestion but I'm not too sure what went wrong:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CustWithHighestOrder
    RETURN NUMBER
    
IS
    l_custkey  orders.o_custkey%TYPE;
    
BEGIN
   SELECT query1.o_custkey
     INTO l_custkey
     FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
               FROM orders
           GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query1,
          (SELECT MAX (query2.ordercount) AS orderhighest
             FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
                       FROM orders
                   GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query2) query3
    WHERE query1.ordercount = query3.orderhighest;
    
    
    
END;
```

Am I supposed to do a  `RETURN l_custkey` before ending so I can use the variable?

Comment: Rather than giving an XY-problem where you only tell us what you think you ought to be doing next but you don't tell us what the ultimate goal is. Why don't you explain the complete problem? It is probably going to end up with a much simpler solution than if you try to break it down into tiny increments.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was because I just found out that there's a difference between a function and stored function. But I'm trying to create a stored function that is able to return the customer that has the highest number of orders to be put inside a variable where I'd be able to then use it in another part of the function to retrieve that customer's data.

Comment: Not sure what this means: *I just found out that there's a difference between a function and stored function*. Did you mean an anonymous block and a function?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm still catching up with the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can simplify your query to:

```sql
SELECT o_custkey
FROM   orders
GROUP BY o_custkey
ORDER BY COUNT(o_orderkey) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Or, before Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT o_custkey
FROM   (
  SELECT o_custkey,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(o_orderkey) DESC) rnk
  FROM   orders
  GROUP BY o_custkey
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

> Now I have to find a way to use the `Custkey` part of the result, insert it into a variable so that I'll be able to use it to query another table for the rest of the customer information.

Unless the variable is going to be used in multiple places for querying different tables, you probably are best just to incorporate the first query into the second query where you find the additional customer information and do it all within a single query rather than having repeated context-switches between the SQL and PL/SQL scopes.

If you then want to use it in another query then use a `JOIN` to include it into that query as a sub-query. Something like:

```sql
SELECT ot.*
FROM   other_table ot
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT o_custkey
         FROM   orders
         GROUP BY o_custkey
         ORDER BY COUNT(o_orderkey) DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       ) max_orders
       ON (ot.o_custkey = max_orders.o_custkey)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! The explanation was very clear cut and the simplification of the query helped a lot. I'll be trying to create my stored function with this.

Answer (score 0):

Then don't `select *` but only what you need.

As it is PL/SQL, declare a local variable and select `INTO` it.

Such a way presumes that query you posted returns only one row; otherwise, it'll raise `too_many_rows` (so you'll have to modify it to select into a collection or process data in a loop (which is usually worse option)) or `no_data_found` (you'll have to handle, somehow).

```
DECLARE
   l_custkey  orders.o_custkey%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT query1.o_custkey
     INTO l_custkey
     FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
               FROM orders
           GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query1,
          (SELECT MAX (query2.ordercount) AS orderhighest
             FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
                       FROM orders
                   GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query2) query3
    WHERE query1.ordercount = query3.orderhighest;
END;
```

---

How to convert it to a function? Simply:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test 
  RETURN orders.o_custkey%TYPE
IS
   l_custkey  orders.o_custkey%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT query1.o_custkey
     INTO l_custkey
     FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
               FROM orders
           GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query1,
          (SELECT MAX (query2.ordercount) AS orderhighest
             FROM (  SELECT o_custkey, COUNT (o_orderkey) AS ordercount
                       FROM orders
                   GROUP BY orders.o_custkey) query2) query3
    WHERE query1.ordercount = query3.orderhighest;

  RETURN l_custkey;
END;
```

All other objections still stand. Also, we *usually* pass parameter(s) to the function and get something in return. Though, as is, that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me reach where I wanted to. But now I'm stuck at trying to change it to a stored function (have included it in the edits). Could you help take a look at it if you have the time? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer and demonstrated how to convert an anonymous PL/SQL block into a function. Have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized I was getting errors mainly because I left the declare clause in, major facepalms, but thank you for your help!